# Redirect to the next page in my facebook app

Tags: facebook, redirect, navigation, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-iframe

I'm building a facebook in which users can give feedback on competences of another user.
In the first step the user selects some competences. When the user clicks on the "go to the next step" button the selected competences are saved in a database and the user will go to the next step.
I have trouble doing the redirect.

This is the code I use for the redirect

```
// build the url for the next step
CanvasUrlBuilder canvasUrlBuilder = new CanvasUrlBuilder();
var uri = canvasUrlBuilder.BuildCanvasPageUrl("/Step2.aspx");
// goto the next step
Response.Redirect(uri.AbsoluteUri);
```

This code is in the OnClick eventhandler of the button.
When the code is hit I get redirected to a blank page within the FB iframe. When manually change the url of the page to url I redirect to I get the correct content.

When I use the following code I get multiple redirects before I end up on the correct page.

```
Response.Redirect("/Step2.aspx");
```

What is the best way to have a facebook app within an iframe containing multiple pages.

I'm using the latest c# sdk (5.3.2.0)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of handling onclick of button on server side, just use:

```
<a href="/Step2.aspx">next page</a>
```

thus you handle http vs https issue.

Comment: Do you also suggest I use Ajax to save values to a database?
I now use the onclick event of the button in which I save values to the database. After saving I want to redirect to the next step.